# HTML5 Canvas Gauge: Assign Rotation value with an input range

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a gauge indicator that the rotation of the indicator is changed with a slider.

I am trying with

```
setInterval(function(){ctx.rotate($("#dial").val);})
```

but nothing..

have a look

http://jsfiddle.net/X23AD/

thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok you just need to use:

```
$("#dial").val()
```

Instead of:

```
$("#dial").val
```

Remember that [**val**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a function of jQuery

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X23AD/1/)